# vuetify grid styles dissapear after build

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vue-cli, npm-run

I've not been able to find a solution :-S

Surely is a basic question, but it's breaking my mind.

I have a very simple app with VUE & VUETIFY. I've been using some grid classes from the examples of vuetify, as for example **.col-md-6**

When I run te app with *npm run serve*, everything works correctly, but when I run *npm run build*, those classes did'nt work at all. I've been looking for those styles, and they are missing. There are some vuetify styles in the head that are not complete, maybe thats the problem...

[image]

On my package.json I don't have anythin special, but probably I'm missing something. I would appreciate your help:

```
  "name": "ecosecha",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.6",
    "vuetify": "^2.2.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.2.3",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.2.3",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.2.3",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.2.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "sass": "^1.25.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.0.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

This is my public repo, maybe It can be helpful: https://github.com/lopandpe/ecosecha

Thanks!

Comment: what version of the vue-cli did you use for bootstrapping the project?

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay, I didn't see your answer. I'm using @vue/cli 4.2.2